# Is there a way to embed a specific cell from a Google Sheets to Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-workspace

I want to fill in a sentence with blank spaces on Google Docs from information that I can provide from Google Sheets. Is this possible?

"For my student number X = [student_number], the required power is [motor_power] kW, and the SMALLEST motor that can meet the required transmitted power requirement has a rated speed of [motor_rpm] RPM."

I want to embed or link a cell from Google Sheets to autofill the [boxes] in Google Docs

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Short answer: It's not possible. If you need further help, please show what you tried, add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As Ruben pointed out, there is no simple *dynamic* way to "autofill" the "boxes" in a Google Docs text document with data from a Google Sheet.

But it is fairly straightforward to do the same *statically*: use a mail merge utility such as [AutoCrat](https://cloudlab.newvisions.org/autocrat). See the [AutoCrat User's Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WTGSSlH6gwUHpipusPKLIsgfFUamDbFbJ7JaoG6-ZBo/edit#heading=h.2hjxm8x81t8b) for more info — you are probably looking for the [Single Document output mode](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WTGSSlH6gwUHpipusPKLIsgfFUamDbFbJ7JaoG6-ZBo/edit#heading=h.bb8f4za4fdxj) option.